# Make DIV stay in center but with scrollbars when page resized

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, margin

I have a DIV that I need to remain centered in a page, even when the page is re-sized.

I have currently acheived this by top:50%; left:50% and top and left margins equal to half the dimenstions of the DIV, like so:

```
.centered {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

However, when the page is made smaller than 500x200, the left side of the div is cut off, and there is no scrollbar to see it's content.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/16c91n5t/1/)

How can I add a scrollbar so that you can see all of the DIV's content?

Thanks

Comment: maybe u can use `vertical-align:middle` but this require that u give the div a `display: inline-block` check @http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1):

Since your element has `position : absolute`, it is cut out off the normal page rendering flow, so there is not way to add a scrollbar without JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a different position: selection that I could make to achieve this?

Comment: unfortunately there is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply user css media query for the specific width and height
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/16c91n5t/3/)

```
   .centered {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 510px) , screen and (max-height:210px) {
    .centered {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer has been updated

Answer (score 0):

```
.centered {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:calc(50% - 250px);
    left:calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

Hope that this helps! This example does require CSS3, so use it in Chrome or Safari for the best results. If you are using a LESS Compiler, you have to change it to be:

```
.centered {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:calc(~"50% - 250px");
    left:calc(~"50% - 100px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting `height` in `%`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.centered {
  width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">This is the div that needs to be centered This is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis
  is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is
  the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the
  div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div
  that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that
  needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs
  to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to
  be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centeredThis is the div that needs to be centered</div>
```